# Java receipt file from .txt

Tags: java, printing

I'm creating a program which will print a *.txt* receipt of the bought items from the store
and it prints successfully, but I need to change the font of some specific part of the text is it possible?
for example I wanted to print something like this

> **THIS SHOULD BE BOLD and BIGGER**
>
> this should be smaller than the first line
>
> *This should be italicized*

would it be possible?

**UPDATE**

here is the code of the printing process

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException {
    String defaultPrinter =PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
    System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);

    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("sample.txt"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet  pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));


    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(in, flavor, null);

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
    in.close();

    // send FF to eject the page
    InputStream ff = new ByteArrayInputStream("\f".getBytes());
    Doc docff = new SimpleDoc(ff, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob jobff = service.createPrintJob();
    pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(jobff);
    jobff.print(docff, null);
    pjw.waitForDone();
  }
}

class PrintJobWatcher {
  boolean done = false;

  PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
    job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
      public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
        allDone();
      }
      void allDone() {
        synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
          done = true;
          System.out.println("Printing done ...");
          PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  public synchronized void waitForDone() {
    try {
      while (!done) {
        wait();
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
```

Comment: where are you printing it?

Comment: EPSON 6510B Thermal Receipt Printer

Comment: How exactly are you printing it? Post your code.

Comment: what language development use?

Comment: I was told to just use ESC/POS commands? but I don't know how to use it... can anyone help me with ESC/POS?

Comment: Try [here](http://www.epsondevelopers.com/home/guides_redirect) to request a Programming guide (which contain printer control codes).

Comment: @PM77-1 I got a ESC/POS code [here](https://code.google.com/p/escprinter/source/browse/trunk/net/drayah/matrixprinter/ESCPrinter.java?r=2) but it needs a network printer I need to print on a local printer

Comment: What network has to do with control codes?

Answer (score 0):

Example for **Bold** (assuming that your printer has the same escape sequences as in the code you linked to).

```
public static final char ESC =  27;
public static final String BOLD_ON = ESC + "E";
public static final String BOLD_OFF = ESC + "F";

String textString = "some text";
String toPrintInBold = BOLD_ON + textString + BOLD_OFF;
```

Now `toPrintInBold` is ready to be set to the printer.

If it works, then you have a method and just need more control codes.

Comment: does this still need to be in a .txt file?

Comment: You have two options: put encoding into your text file which is a bit tricky because of ESC character or read your file line by line and do encoding on the fly.  The latter I think will be easier. `Scanner` class is good at reading lines from text files.